# Riemann, Ricci and Weyl tensors

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, curvature

To simply put, my understanding on Riemann, Ricci and Weyl tensors so far was:

- Riemann tensor describes the curvature of spacetime / whether spacetime is flat or not e.g. when $R_{\lambda \mu \nu \rho}=0$, spacetime is flat.
- Ricci tensor describes the matter content in a region of spacetime / whether spacetime is empty or not e.g. when $R_{\lambda \mu}=0$, spacetime is empty. Additionally, it describes how the shape of the body is distorted by tidal forces.
- Weyl tensor describes how Riemann tensor behaves outside the matter distribution. Additionally, it describes how the shape of the body is distorted by tidal forces just like Ricci tensor, and it describes the propagation of gravitational waves in the absence of matter ($\sim$ flat spacetime).

First of all, doesn't flatness of spacetime locally imply absence of matter and absence of matter imply flatness? $R_{\lambda \mu \nu \rho} \leftrightarrow R_{\lambda \mu}$

I would appreciate if you can add more physical insight on Riemann, Ricci and Weyl tensors.

Comment: Hint to see why the absence of matter doesn't imply absence of curvature: consider the Schwarzschild (vacuum) solution

Comment: Flatness implies absence of sources, i.e., mass. However absence of mass does not imply absence of curvature just because it propagates from sources...

Comment: To add up on the above comment, regarding the $R_{\lambda\mu\nu\rho} \leftrightarrow R_{\lambda\mu}$ correspondence you wrote. The Ricci tensor is the trace of the Riemann curvature tensor. Vanishing of a trace does not imply that the whole tensor vanishes. In physical terms it is equivalent to saying that absence of Ricci curvature (or matter sources $T_{\mu\nu}$) does NOT imply that spacetime curvature vanishes.